# Using jquery to take action on a click event of a a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am I missing here?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script>

               $("a").click(function() {
                  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
                  window.location.reload();
            });

    </script>
           <li><a id='fu' href="change_password" target="content">Change Password</a>
           <li><a id='fu' href="delete_user" target="content">Delete User</a></li>
```

I click and I get no alert......

Comment: could be onDomReady hasn't fired yet. Try wrapping in $(document).ready(function(){ ... });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

document.ready(function() - if the element doesn't exist in the dom at the time of binding then no event handlers will be attached to the element.  Use document ready function to wait for dom to be ready before trying to bind event handlers to elements

```
// this is equivalent to $(document).ready(function()
$(function(){ // <-- wait for dom ready before binding events
 $("a").click(function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault(); //<-- not sure if you want anchor action - if not add this in
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        window.location.reload();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when your JavaScript is executed, it refers to elements which do not exist on the page yet.

You can either execute your JavaScript when the DOM is ready (your JavaScript will wait for all elements on the page to be loaded before executing):

```
<script>
$(document).on("ready", function(){
    $("a").click(function() {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        window.location.reload();
    });
});
</script>
```

Or put your JavaScript at the end of the page (all elements will be loaded when it finally runs).